# Hide div if page was visited

Tags: jquery, cookies

I'm using  carhartl / jquery-cookie plugin.
I'm looking for solution how to hide the same divs in few pages in my domain.
On first visit div1 should be show and div2 hide on next visits div2 show and div1 hide.
The same action should work for every pages.
But my code work only on first visit for first page if another page is open script show div2 and hide div1
I'm not familiar with cookie and jquery can anybody help ?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var visited = $.cookie('visited')
    if (visited == null) {
    $('.div1').show();
    $('.div2').hide();     ``
    } else {
    $('.div1').hide();
    $('.div2').show();
    }
    $.cookie('visited', 'yes_visited', { expires: 1 });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to share the cookie across multiple pages then try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var visited = $.cookie('visited')
    if (visited == null) {
        $('.div1').show();
        $('.div2').hide();
    } else {
        $('.div1').hide();
        $('.div2').show();
    }
    $.cookie('visited', 'yes_visited', {
        expires: 1,
        path: '/'
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LEyrj/), [another version](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LEyrj/2/)

Comment: +1 for a good answer Johny, as always, but you still need to work on explaining things.  Teach them to fish!

Comment: I'm try using path: '/' but it's not help still work in first visit

Comment: @Radi it seems to be working for me...  when I visited test.html first time 123 was displayed... then i refreshed so 456 was displayed... then I clicked test2.html again 456 was displayed

Comment: Yes but I need show in all pages 123 for first visit and for next visits 456. Example: first visit test.htm show 123 all next visits show 456, first visit test1.htm show 123 all next visits show 456. How to get proper code ? :)